# Pinch from every point with Hammerjs

Tags: angular, hammer.js, pinchzoom

Currently, I'm working with **hammer.js** with the following example:
https://bl.ocks.org/redgeoff/fe2e55fe710f341c335ba445569d1783

With this example, it's only possible to pinch from the middle. If I remove the *marginLeft and marginTop attr*, it's only possible to pinch from the top right.

My goal is to pinch from every point, where you start pinching. Without using CSS transform, unless there is no other option.

I've tried adding the following meta tag to the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=yes">
```

But that doesn't work for me.